# google chrome: any extensions for code syntax highlighting on some website?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, syntax-highlighting

any extensions for code syntax highlighting on some website?

Answer (score 1):

'[Code Highlight](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ljgkhjkajfkphkgndbhokcoglecihaia?hl=en)' seems to do that.

Comment: akira: i'm merging the [firefox-addons] and [chrome-extensions] tags into [browser-addons] (and/or [plugins] if necessary).  [firefox-addons] is big and i'm doing it slowly to make sure they're also tagged [firefox] if needed (and to avoid spamming the front page).  please don't recreate [chrome-extensions].

Answer (score 0):

here you have: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-source-viewer/cfmcghennfbpmhemnnfjhkdmnbidpanb

very very good

[image]